# Conditional check and lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection "data" with documents in following format.

```
{
  name: "A",
  file: "/path/to/file"
}
```

The `file` key doesn't exist in all documents. If it doesn't exist I can lookup another collection `files_info` and get the `file` key and value as follows.

```
db.data.aggregate([
  { "$lookup" : {
    "from": "files_info",
    "localField": "name",
    "foreignField": "name",
    "as": "files"  
  }},
  { "$project" : {
    "file" : "$files.file"
  }}
])
```

Is it possible to conditionally check if the key `file` exists in collection `data`, if it does project from `data.file`, if it doesn't exist lookup `files_info` and project as `$files.file`?

Comment: there is no conditional lookup with the collection, you can try [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet) to separate the result.

Comment: But I don't want to seperate the results. Is there any other approach to achieve the result described in the question?

Comment: why would I not instruct you in the first comment if is there any other approach? i don't think any other approach available to achieve this.

Comment: Okay, will try that approach. Thanks